# how to make keyboard go away when enter is press

Tags: android

O my acer tablet the return does not get replace by done with the following xml, but does on my other 2 android devices

So I was going to use the return key to exit the keyboard as a bck up,
problem, I figured out how to do the call back when enter key is press, but don't know how to make the keyboard go away,
code

```
mUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.viewUserName);
        mUserName.setOnEditorActionListener(
                new android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
                {
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
                    {
                        // goes here when enter is press

                        return false;
                    }
                }


                );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your xml for the edit text, set the imeOptions. Basically just add this line:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

This will change the enter button to a "done" button, and dismiss your keyboard when pressed.

-OR-

You can add this inside the code block from above

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);
```